# Login Failed you cant use facebook to log into this app or website because there's an issue with its implementation of facebook login (NuxtJs App)

Tags: facebook, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I tried to implement firebase authentication for my NuxtJs app for facebook social media login, but even after I made sure that all settings are correct (including hash and firebase settings), Facebook always threw this vague error.

> Login Failed you cant use facebook to log into this app or website because there's an issue with its implementation of facebook login

I have another NuxtJs app that also uses firebase authentication for Facebook login and it works perfectly. I've made sure all the settings are the same with my currently problematic NuxtJs app. What could be the reason for Facebook throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait never mind it works now. Apparently it's all because my NuxtJs app was being restricted by Facebook for violating their policies. After appealing the restriction, it's now working perfectly well.

The error message was so vague that I didn't think it was because my app was restricted by Facebook. But it seems like that was really the answer. I think Facebook should make the error message a bit clearer that it was caused by the app being restricted.

Anyway, thanks for the help folks.